# How to show fees paid on show_transfers command in monero cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transfer

Using the show_transfers command on monero-cli, it doesn't show the fee paid. It only shows the full amount. Also what do each column represent in show_transfers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does in fact show the fee.
For incoming transaction, the columns in the `show_transfers` output are:

```
<block_height> in <date> <amount_received> <txid> <payment_id>
```

For outgoing transaction:

```
<block_height> out <date> <total_amount_sent> <txid> <payment_id> <fee> <receiving_addr_1> <amount_1> <receiving_addr_2> <amount_2> ...
```

Another option is to get the txid of the transaction you need, using `show_transfers`, and then you can run `show_transfer <txid>` (that's a different command, no 's' at the end) to get more details about this specific transaction, which includes the fee.

Comment: You can send to multiple addresses and just pay a one time fee?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can see the exact command format by running `help` in the cli and look for the `transfer` command.